# Custom Android Ratingbar

Tags: java, android

I want to implement a custom RatingBar in my workout app. The bar should have 4 stars and a stepsize of 1. The layout looks like this:

```
<com.example.workouttest.MyBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="4"
    android:numStars="4"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:scaleX="0.6"
    android:scaleY="0.6"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

I want to replace the default stars with custom images. But each of the 4 stars should have a different image:

Star 1 = an "X" that means "this item is disabled"

Star 2 = Thumb down

Star 3 = something that represents a "neutral rating"

Star 4 = Thumb up

Addtitionally when, for example, the item is rated with a 3 (neutral rating), all other stars (1,2 and 4) should display a greyed out version of their image.

I tried to extend from RatingBar and came up with the following code:

```
public class MyBar extends RatingBar {

    private int[] starArrayColor = {
            R.drawable.star_1_color,
            R.drawable.star_2_color,
            R.drawable.star_3_color,
            R.drawable.star_4_color
    };

    private int[] starArrayGrey = {
            R.drawable.star_1_grey,
            R.drawable.star_2_grey,
            R.drawable.star_3_grey,
            R.drawable.star_4_grey
    };

    public MyBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int stars = getNumStars();
        float rating = getRating();

        for (int i=0;i<stars;i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            Resources res = getResources();
            Paint paint = new Paint();

            if ((int) rating == i) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, starArrayColor[i]);
            } else {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, starArrayGrey[i]);
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            canvas.save();
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Sadly it did not work. It draws just the normal stars with my custom images as background.

Is here someone who knows how to help me solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Gabe my working onDraw method now looks like this:

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int stars = getNumStars();
    float rating = getRating();
    float x = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<stars;i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Resources res = getResources();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        x += 50;

        if ((int) rating-1 == i) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, starArrayColor[i]);
        } else {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, starArrayGrey[i]);
        }
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 48, 48, true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, x, 0, paint);
        canvas.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: can we do with half rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call super.onDraw-  that will draw the normal stars.  From there, what else doesn't work?

Comment: Oh thanks for this little hint. After I got this working I realised that my replacement images have all been drawn. But all on the same spot. I've added the new (experimental) onDraw method to my question.

Comment: You don't need canvas.save, that's only needed if you want to use different matrices for a little while.  Not sure if that would screw things up or not.  Otherwise the code looks about right.  Without that are you still only getting 1 image drawn?

Comment: You are right, canvas.save is not needed. In the first code they have all been drawn at x and y = 0. But it is really working nice now.